# Why can't i toggle between my navbar button and my close button?

Tags: reactjs, toggle, sidebar

So when i click on the navbar icon, my sidebar doesn't show up though i make the *nav-menu* to be *left -100px* and the *nav-menu.active* to be *left 0*. I don't know what is wrong? anybody can help me? Thank you so much!

This is my Navbar.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import * as FaIcons from "react-icons/fa";
import * as AiIcons from "react-icons/ai";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { SidebarData } from "./SidebarData";
import "./Navbar.css";

function Navbar() {
  const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);

  const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!setSidebar);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="navbar">
        <Link to="#" className="menu-bars">
          <FaIcons.FaBars onClick={showSidebar} />{" "}
        </Link>{" "}
      </div>{" "}
      <nav className={sidebar ? "nav-menu active" : "nav-menu"}>
        <ul className="nav-menu-items">
          <li className="navbar-toggle">
            <Link to="#" className="menu-bars">
              <AiIcons.AiFillCloseSquare />
            </Link>{" "}
          </li>{" "}
          {SidebarData.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
                <Link to={item.path}>
                  {" "}
                  {item.icon} <span> {item.title} </span>{" "}
                </Link>{" "}
              </li>
            );
          })}{" "}
        </ul>{" "}
      </nav>{" "}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

This is my Navbar.css:

```
.navbar {
    background-color: aquamarine;
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
}

.nav-menu {
    background-color: aquamarine;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    transition: 850ms;
}

.nav-menu.active {
    left: 0;
    transition: 350ms;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to negate your state updater function:

```
const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!setSidebar);
```

You want to toggle the state instead:

```
const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);
const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(show => !show);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!setSidebar);
```

into

```
const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!sidebar);
```